# Sending email from a Sinatra web app using the Heroku SendGrid add-on

Tags: ruby, email, heroku, sinatra, sendgrid

I'm trying to set up SendGrid to send email via a simple web form in a Sinatra app.

I have enabled the SendGrid add-on in Heroku, and checked the environment vars via `heroku config`; both `SENDGRID_USERNAME` and `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` are set.

I have also created a Sender Identity on the SendGrid website, which has been verified.

When I submit the form I get:

> "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed"

When I click the "Twilio SendGrid" add-on link on the Heroku dashboard, I'm  forwarded to a page on the SendGrid website, which says:

> Access to sendgrid.com was denied. You don't have authorisation to view this page.
> HTTP ERROR 403

Methods & settings for sending email are below:

```
post '/contact' do
 configure_options
 Pony.mail(
    :from => [params[:name], "<", params[:email], ">"].join,
    :to => 'hi@mydomain.com',
    :subject =>  ["Opt-in via /contact: ", params[:name]].join,
    :body => [params[:name], params[:email]].join(": ")
  )
  redirect '/'
end

def configure_options
  Pony.options = {
    :via => :smtp,
    :via_options => {
      :address              => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      :port                 => '587',
      :domain               => 'heroku.com',
      :user_name            => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password             => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
  }
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: A protip that can save you tons of debugging time is to use `ENV.fetch('SENDGRID_USERNAME')` instead. It will raise a KeyError if the key is missing and fail early instead of just getting `nil` which causes a crash down the line.

Comment: I get `-bash: ENV.fetch: command not found` when trying this command!

Comment: You're supposed to use it instead of `ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` in your Ruby code. Not from bash. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch

Comment: Ah, gotcha. And you were right; I get `<KeyError: key not found: "SENDGRID_USERNAME">`— which is a perplexing given that the output of `heroku config` is  `SENDGRID_USERNAME: app125434023@heroku.com
`.

Comment: That is kind of odd. If you start up IRB or pry with `heroku run irb` does the ENV hash contain the expected values?

Comment: Yes, it does — both username and pwd match what is returned by `heroku config`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped. Ruby will allow you to resassign constants with a warning. So you code could potentially overwrite the ENV hash. You would have noticed that on you local machine though.

Comment: No problem and thanks for the help. I suspect that the problem is on the SendGrid side — configuring their service for *receiving* email is not very well documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SendGrid does not *receive* any mail so any requests you are making to SendGrid would be to send mail.

This means that you first need to set up an entity you control, and which can act as a sender even if the recipient is yourself.

You do this by creating a Sender Identity. This is the procedure when sending mail via SMTP:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api/

Next, you need to crate an API key. SendGrid no longer supports basic authentication, so this code will not work:

```
  :user_name            => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
```

Instead, you need to use:

```
  :user_name            => 'apikey',
  :password             => 'your-api-key',
```

where `'apikey'` is the literal string `'apikey'`, and `'your-api-key'` is the 69-character API key generated by SendGrid (and shown only once).

Then, in your POST method:

```
    post '/contact' do
     configure_options
     Pony.mail(

        # the :from field below is the email address 
        # associated with your SendGrid Sender Identity:
        :from => 'yourname@email.com',
        :to => 'someother@email.com',

        :subject =>  ["Opt-in via /contact: ", params[:name]].join,
        :body => [params[:name], params[:email]].join(": ")
      )
      redirect '/'
    end
```